# Trying to access GPS with Gluon, but app shuts down unexpectedly

Tags: android, javafx, gps, gluon

I had been trying to know if my GPS state is enabled, and if not it will enable and give me the location coordinates. But whenever I launch the app and click on the button to get coordinates, the app shuts down unexpectedly.

My code is as below:

```
button.setOnAction(e->{
        PositionService positionService = Services.get(PositionService.class).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("PositionService not available."));
        positionService.positionProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> MobileApplication.getInstance().showMessage("Latest known GPS coordinates from device: " + nv.getLatitude() + ", " + nv.getLongitude()));
    });
```

I found the code in Gluon Mobile's documentation.

Here is my build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.10'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.test.GluonTestApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.1'
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:2.0.0';
    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-desktop:2.0.0';
    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-android:2.0.0';
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-ios:2.0.0';
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-plugin-position', 
    version: '3.7.0'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.7.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your 
project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage', 'position'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = 'C:/Users/Mainul/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Note: I have also added the Position permission in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Connect your device, and on your machine open a terminal, go to your Android sdk folder, enter `platform-tools` folder, and run `adb logcat -v threadtime`. Now run your app again, click the button and find the stacktrace on the console. Post it here or try to figure out why it is happening.

Comment: You misunderstood me or I didn't express myself correctly... Go to your Android SDK folder (otherwise you couldn't run JavaFXPorts/Gluon), enter `platform-tools`, and run the `adb` program as mentioned above, to find out what is going on with your app and why it crashes.

Comment: I tried but can't track the lines in the black tint cmd screen. Is there any other way to track them?

Comment: You can redirect the log to a file `adb logcat -v threadtime > txt.log` while running the app, and then review it.

Comment: I could not access the log while debugging with real device. But in desktop run the following exceptions are shown.

`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: The service PositionService can't be registered. Call Services.registerServiceFactory() with a valid ServiceFactory
 at com.gluonhq.charm.down.Services.get(Services.java:74)
 at com.gluonapplication.test.BasicView.lambda$new$2(BasicView.java:29)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
`

Comment: The same log is shown in the real devices.

Comment: Did you add the `position` service to the `downConfig` section of the `build.gradle` file? Can you post this file?

Comment: Yes, I did, also I added `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in android manifest.

Comment: Post your build.gradle so we can see what is your setup

Comment: I posted the build.gradle code in the answer below.

Comment: Remove the answer and edit your question and post it there.

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions for GPS? Since Android 21 you have to request dangerous permissions on runtime: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up old and new dependencies for Charm Down.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.1'

    // (1)
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:2.0.0';
    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-desktop:2.0.0';
    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-android:2.0.0';
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-ios:2.0.0';

    // (2)
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-plugin-position', version: '3.7.0'
}
```

For starters, the latest Charm Down version is 3.7.0, so all the "2.0.0" dependencies in (1) are not required anymore.

Also, `downConfig` manages to add the required Charm Down dependencies, so you don't need to include any of them inside `dependencies {}`, (2).

Just remove those from (1) and (2):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.1'
}
```

Clean and deploy again.